# JavaFX - How to sync multiple WAV files?

Tags: java, audio

I'm making a sound player in Java with JavaFX and I'm trying to make multiple WAV files play in sync. But when I call the method which makes my clip.start() run for each file, they are completely out of sync.

This is the code for the method I'm calling when I press my button (play).

```
private Clip playSound(ArrayList<File> files) {
        for (File file : files) {
            try {
                AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
                clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
                clip.open(audioInputStream);
                clip.start();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.print("Sound file open error\n " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        return clip;
    }
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Add a boolean to check if the song is still playing, and if it is, wait

Comment: But how does this fix the non-syncing files?

Comment: I misunderstood your question, my bad. So by sync, what do you mean? I interpreted as you meant that you needed them to play like a playlist. Edit: I just realized you want them to play together, or maybe I'm wrong. But if I'm right, maybe try playing all the files with a for loop in the try, and then catch

Comment: Yes, I meant that I want all of them playing at the same time, not after each other.

Answer (score 0):

I've not used this method myself (I wrote my own mixer, instead), but according to the tutorial [Playing Back Audio](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/playing.html) (see bottom section *Synchronizing Playback on Multiple Lines*) and documentation on [Mixer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/sound/sampled/Mixer.html), there exist Mixers that support the synchronization you describe.

It is possible to specify the `Mixer` when creating a `Clip` rather than using the default `Mixer` as you do in the code you show. The syntax should be straightforward to locate in the API. But as to whether there's a `Mixer` that will work for a given OS and PC, I have little experience with this. If the [isSynchronizationSupported](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/sound/sampled/Mixer.html#isSynchronizationSupported(javax.sound.sampled.Line%5B%5D,boolean)) test doesn't work on the default mixer, I'm guessing you just have to iterate and test all available Mixers and hope for the best. IDK.

As I said, I've side-stepped the problem. I am using a mixer that I wrote which handles adding together the PCM data from the constituent "Clips" (actually, `AudioCue`s, which are based on `Clip`s). With this library you could create and 'play' the audioCues with the mixer off, and then start them all at once by [starting the Mixer](http://adonax.com/AudioCue/api/src/main/java/com/adonax/audiocue/AudioMixer.html#start--). The library allows multiple instances of `AudioMixer` to be running independently, at the same time, if you have more than one set of cues you are trying to synchronize.

You are welcome to use the [AudioCue](https://github.com/philfrei/AudioCue) library. Or you might just inspect the mixing code and write your own. An important benefit of this approach is that this library is not as susceptible to variations in OS implementation of mixer capabilities. Functionality is handled at the PCM level on a `SourceDataLine`, a reliable class.